# rapidminer and sentiment analysis

Tags: nlp

Is anyone out there used Rapidminer for sentiment analysis... Is this a right combination???

If not how do I get started with a simple sentiment analysis application??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RapidMiner is a very powerful text mining and sentiment analysis tools. I can recommend the RapidMiner training courses offered by Rapid-I. They gave me a really quick start. They also offer a dedicated course on text mining and sentiment analysis:
[Sentiment Analysis, Opinion Mining, and Automated Market Research](http://rapid-i.com/content/view/125/150/) .

Starting in September or October 2009, they will also offer webinars. You should contact  them directly, if you would like to learn more about their webinars. Several major online market research companies in Europe and the US are using RapidMiner for opinion mining and sentiment analysis from internet discussions groups and web blogs. For more details and references I would again suggest to simply ask their team at contact(at)rapid-i.com or check their RapidMiner forum at forum.rapid-i.com .

Best regards,

Frank

Answer (score 1):

This series of videos should help:

http://vancouverdata.blogspot.com/2010/11/text-analytics-with-rapidminer-loading.html

Answer (score 0):

When I go to rapid miner site it is confusing me.

http://rapidminer.com/solutions/sentiment-analysis/

"It looks like a crowd sourcing to identify the polarity of product reviews and discussions around the web." If you are looking to automate in real time this might not be a good solution.

[spotdy.com](https://www.spotdy.com) offers free NLP for developers. It works pretty cool.

Most of the Sentiment Analysis software tokenize words and giving a positive and negative factor and sum those up. Since language is contextual, this leads to ignoring the context which is not a right way to do.

Instead deep learning models, HMM based on sentence structure.  It computes the sentiment based on how words are composed in a sentence. Check out spotdy.com. It is free.